# VBA IsMissing Returns False Missing Parameter

Tags: vba

I am trying to create a wrapper function for Datediff function. It will have an optional parameter for the interval. I want to check if the parameter was passed. I thought I could use the IsMissing() function on the parameter. However, it returns false when the optional parameter wasn't passed

```
Public Function test1(tdDate1 As Date, tdDate2 As Date, Optional tcInterval As String) As Long
    Debug.Print IsMissing(tcInterval)
End Function
```

Here's output:

```
?test1(#01/15/2020#,#01/16/2021#)
False
 0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Either remove `As String` or test for a blank string instead of using `IsMissing`

Comment: Thanks, that did it!

Answer (score 3):

`IsMissing` just works for `Variants`. From [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ismissing-function)

> Use the IsMissing function to detect whether or not optional Variant arguments have been provided in calling a procedure. IsMissing returns True if no value has been passed for the specified argument; otherwise, it returns False. (...)

> IsMissing does not work on simple data types (such as Integer or Double) because, unlike Variants, they don't have a provision for a "missing" flag bit

If you want to check if a string parameter was passed, provide a default value and check for that, or change parameter type to `Variant` - but then you loose type safety.

```
Public Function test1(tdDate1 As Date, tdDate2 As Date, Optional tcInterval As String="") 
    If tcInterval="" then
        Debug.Print "No Interval value passed."
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score -2):

You should *validate* the interval setting:

```vb
Public Function test1(tdDate1 As Date, tdDate2 As Date, Optional ByVal tcInterval As String) As Long

    Select Case tcInterval
        Case "s", "n", "h", "d", "m", "q", "y", "yyyy", "w", "ww"
            ' OK.
        Case Else
            ' Apply a default interval.
            tcInterval = "d"
    End Select

    ' Do DateDiff stuff.
    test1 = DateDiff(tcInterval, tdDate1, tdDate2)

End Function
```